# Magento - Create database view

Tags: database, magento, view

Table could be created like this:

```
<?php 
$installer = $this; 
$installer->startSetup();
$installer->run("
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS {$this->getTable('sample_table')};
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS {$this -> getTable ('sample_table')} (`id` INT (10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL COMMENT 'primary key', `name` INT (10) NULL COMMENT 'name')
");
$installer->endSetup();
```

But I have no idea how to create a database view in the above way, which looks like:

```
CREATE VIEW SAMPLE_VIEW AS 
SELECT A.NAME, B.NAME FROM TABLE_A A
INNER JOIN TABLE_B B ON A.FIELD_1 = B.FIELD_1;
```

Any way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

I'm have not tested the below code but it may be helpful to you.

```
<?php
$installer = $this;
$installer->startSetup();
// This will work fine
$installer->run("CREATE VIEW SAMPLE_VIEW AS SELECT A.entity_id, A.type_id, B.path
    FROM `catalog_product_entity` A
    INNER JOIN `catalog_category_entity` B ON A.entity_id = B.entity_type_id");
// try the below code if you have already model design
$installer->run("CREATE VIEW SAMPLE_VIEW AS SELECT A.entity_id, A.type_id, B.path
    FROM {$this->getTable('your_custom_table')} A
    INNER JOIN {$this->getTable('your_custom_table')} B ON A.entity_id = B.entity_type_id");
$installer->endSetup();
```

Let me know if you have any query.

Thanks.

Comment: I tried but seems it doesn't work. But let me see if any other solution. :)